# I met a lot of answers

Tags: riddle, rhyme

I was once searching for some words that I thought I'd lost, but then someone told me

> If you solve this riddle, brought within rhyme, you will find it again!

After realising I had to find the answer within myself, I found it. Can you?

```
Where people are wearing magic,
That question lies within.
And though it brought me answers,
I still had to ask my non-next-of-kin.

Some will think it's fantasy,
While others think it's science.
There are a lot of people,
Showing off their alliance.

While looking for an answer
A number it will be
One two seven two four seven
Are the digits we now see
```

**HINT #1**

> The words I'm looking for are the title of a book

**HINT #2**

> The title contains two seperate clues

Comment: I wonder if [this](http://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/gene/127247) is related.

Comment: Is it a classic or well known title?  Could we get the answer is we didn't know the book?

Comment: @BrentHackers although it isn't a well known title, you don't need to know the book to solve the puzzle. In fact, the fact it isn't a well known title might just help.

Comment: @PatrickRoberts no, although you're thinking in the right direction

Comment: @PatrickRoberts - your comment helped me quite a bit.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The words are:

> The Spellcoats.
>  This is the name of a book you read a long time ago, but couldn't remember the title of.

Where people are wearing magic,
That question lies within.

> The book contains the concept of: "some kind of special power that involved weaving some kind of clothing."

And though it brought me answers,
I still had to ask my non-next-of-kin.

> You couldn't find the answer to a question, so you had to ask someone.

Some will think it's fantasy,
While others think it's science.
There are a lot of people,
Showing off their alliance.

> You decided to ask your question on the Science Fiction & Fantasy SE site.

While looking for an answer
A number it will be
One two seven two four seven
Are the digits we now see

> This is the anchor link to the answer to your question, which tells you the book title you were looking for:
>  https://scifi.stackexchange.com/a/127247

Comment: Yes, that's it. Do you understand the two clues in the title too?

Comment: Actually no, the second hint was the only part I couldn't match. I gathered you had been searching on and off for a long time, so you would have gotten many (wrong) answers, but I can't figure out what you mean by the word "met".

Comment: Maybe "met a" = Meta SE? Still not sure how that fits either...

Comment: This is a question about a question on stackexchange on stackexchange. So therefore, I thought the word meta would indeed be a good fit.

Comment: Ah yes- that makes sense.

Comment: Lol the only thing relating my comment to this is the fact it's a URL

Comment: @PatrickRoberts - your comment was enough to make me look into URLs containing that number, and since the number was about the length of some SE question numbers, I thought to try it somewhere on SE. Then I just needed to find an SE site that was "fantasy or science" and scifi fit perfectly. So I tried the question number on SciFi, and was pleasantly surprised to see that question was asked by OP, and then it immediately made sense. So Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

I think the book is:

> 1984, is a dystopian novel by English author George Orwell

Because of these lines:

> Some will think it's fantasy,
>  while others think it's science.

And the need is to find the answer within:

> A number it will be
>  One two seven two four seven

Comment: Although it's a good guess, this isn't it

Comment: Lemme try once again!

Answer (score 1):

I think the book is

> Harry Potter and the Philosopher's Stone

Where people are wearing magic,

That question lies within.

> First line might refer to the fact that the book deals with magic, spells...

And though it brought me answers,

I still had to ask my non-next-of-kin

> Harry Potter doesn't know he's a wizard, and the story developes some parts of his life (answers) , but he still had to ask his non-next-of-kin (Voldemort)

Some will think it's fantasy,

While others think it's science

> While the book is a fantasy book. The Philosopher's Stone was a legendary alchemical substance, and long ago, alchemy had the status of science.

There are a lot of people,

Showing off their alliance

> All the students in Hogwarts each of them belonging to one of four different teams, Griffindor, Slytherin, Hufflepuff and Ravenclaw (the alliances)

While looking for an answer

A number it will be

One two seven two four seven

Are the digits we now see

> One two seven cand be read as "One to seven" meaning that the book is the first of a series of seven (?) . And I don't know about the last two lines, maybe the form of Harry's scar, that might look like a four or a seven.

Comment: Although this is a good answer, it's not correct. It also doesn't explain the numbers well, or the title.

Answer (score -2):

Book Title:

> Become a Better You: 7 Keys to Improving Your Life Every Day by Joel
>  Osteen

or

> OOps... The 7 Habits of Highly Effective People: Powerful Lessons in Personal Change, by Stephen Covey...
>  Same reasons...

Why?

> Start at the numbers 127247 and read them as:  1 (TO) 7 ... 24 (hours
>  a day) 7 (days a week.)

And...

> Seven tips, numbered one through 7...

More...

> Add in a little religion, a little bit of science, and you begin to
>  see why Harry Potter is so popular.  Harry Potter, how did he get in here...  oh wait, I mean Joel Osteen... er. no.. Stephen Covey.  Okay, [Hyrum W. Smith](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/0446670642)?  Er.. lets just go with Harry Potter.

Comment: First of all, this isn't really one clear answer, which I guess is why people downvoted your answer, but none of these are correct, although some fit well.

Comment: @dennisvangils Huh?  It's pretty clear the Joel Osteen book (2007) is a total ripoff of the Stephen Covey Book.  From my view it's the same book, hence the double post. And I thought Hyrum Smith did it better, much better.  But... I'm guessing the downvotes without comment are disgruntled Joel Osteen fans without the courage to leave a comment.  Or just folks with no sense of humor.  Thank you Harry Potter.

Comment: As I'm not really familiar with self-help books I didn't know they were the same book, and I'm guessing many other people didn't too.

Comment: @DennisvanGils No, they are not the exactly same book.  I'm pulling your chain.  One is a rip off of a best seller book, with a heavy emphasis on religion (or magic, depending on your point of view.)  You are the one who brought magic into the conversation, right there on line #1 above.  For reference here's the [wiki link to Joel Osteen.](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Joel_Osteen)